# texts are not showing in arraylist and in tab fragments

Tags: android

The text from arraylist and thetab fragment are not showing at all. I don't know whats wrong , can you help me show the texts in the list and in tab fragmetn(second picture). please note that I add a log and the values are showing in the logcat.

[image]

[image]

The codes :
this is profile.java

```
public class Profile extends ListActivity  {

 dbhelper sqlHandler;
 ListView lvCustomList;
 EditText etName, etPhone;
 Button btnsubmit;
 SQLiteDatabase db;
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.profile);
  sqlHandler = new dbhelper(this);
  sqlHandler.openDataBase();
  Log.v("on create","profile");

  List<Comment> values = sqlHandler.getAllComments();
  ArrayAdapter<Comment> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Comment>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
 }

 public void onClick(View view) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ArrayAdapter<Comment> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<Comment>) getListAdapter();
        Comment comment = null;
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.add:
          String[] comments = new String[] { "Cool", "Very nice", "Hate it" };
          int nextInt = new Random().nextInt(3);

          // save the new comment to the database
          comment = sqlHandler.createComment(comments[nextInt]);
          adapter.add(comment);

          break;
        case R.id.delete:
          if (getListAdapter().getCount() > 0) {
            comment = (Comment) getListAdapter().getItem(0);
           // sqlHandler.deleteComment(comment);
            adapter.remove(comment);
          }
          break;
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
  return true;
 }
}
```

dbhelper.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class dbhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
     private SQLiteDatabase database;
    public final static int db_version = 1;
    public final static String db_tab_name ="justtable";
    public final static String db_col_name="f_name";
    public final static String db_f_phone="f_phone";
    public final static String db_col_id ="_id";
    public final static String database_name="databasename";
    public final static String db_create="Create table " + db_tab_name +" ("+db_col_id +" integer primary key autoincrement  ," +db_col_name +" text,"+db_f_phone +" TEXT )";



    public dbhelper(Context context) {
        super(context, database_name, null, db_version);
    }


    public void openDataBase() {
        try {
        database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE "+ db_tab_name);
        database.execSQL(db_create);
        Log.d("l", db_create);
    }catch (Exception e) {

           System.out.println("DATABASE ERROR " + e);
          }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        //database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+ db_tab_name);
        //database.execSQL(db_create);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int arg1, int arg2) {
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+ db_tab_name);
        onCreate( database);
    }
       public boolean insertContact  (String name)
       {
          SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
          ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

          contentValues.put( "name",name);

          db.insert("justtable", null, contentValues);
          db.close();
          return true;
       }


       public Comment createComment(String comment) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(db_col_name, comment);
            long insertId = database.insert(db_tab_name, null,
                values);
            Cursor cursor = database.query(db_tab_name,
                new String[]{db_col_name,db_f_phone}, db_col_id + " = " + insertId, null,
                null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            Comment newComment = cursorToComment(cursor);
            cursor.close();
            return newComment;
          }
       public List<Comment> getAllComments() {
            List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>();

            Cursor cursor = database.query(db_tab_name,
                     new String[]{db_col_name,db_f_phone}, null, null, null, null, null);

            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
              Comment comment = cursorToComment(cursor);
              comments.add(comment);
              cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            // make sure to close the cursor
            cursor.close();
            return comments;
          }

          private Comment cursorToComment(Cursor cursor) {
            Comment comment = new Comment();
            comment.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
            comment.setComment(cursor.getString(1));
            return comment;
          }

}
```

this is code style.xml

```
    style.xml


<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

If you have any question or you need anything else please tell me

Comment: Insted of List<Comment> values use String[] value.

Comment: @Muthu its a list .. how to do it as a string ?

Comment: try iterating list and add them to String array. Since you are using basic listview input should be array.

Comment: @Muthu u still online ?

Comment: yes!  how can i help you budy?

Comment: Ill be glad if you can help me . I am stuck on a really stupid thing .. the problem I am facing is with the cursor .. its not getting any value .. anyway how can go to a chat and discussed there ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78084/discussion-between-moudiz-and-muthu).

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Comment> values = sqlHandler.getAllComments();
```

does this list getting values ?
have u checked ?

Comment: use System.out.println("your values");   and check in logcat you will see the text in green color

Comment: System.out.println("your values");

Comment: yes you right its giving empty .. then whats problem with getallcontact method ? 
 List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>();
      Cursor cursor = database.query(db_tab_name,
         new String[]{db_col_name,db_f_phone}, null, null, null, null, null);

Comment: first you need to install sqlite databse browser to check if tables contains values or not http://sqlitebrowser.org/

Comment: okay I am insatling it now , while that please can you check for me if me the method public Comment createComment(String comment) correct ?

Comment: it seems ohk have to installed brwoser

Comment: see if the table you have created contains value of not ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78075/discussion-between-quick-learner-and-moudiz).